# ReorderTable rows with jQuery but exclude the nested tables

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, dom

I'm trying to exclude nested tables/tr from my Reorder Table script. I have looked at the topic of JQuery and nest tables. Everything I try only work half way.
$("#table tr.table_row1") or $("table > tr.order_rows")

it's in a for loop and picks up the order from an array. I would appreciate any help.

Heres' my code:

```
    <table>
      <tr class="order_rows"> <- pick this row
        <td>
           <table>
             <tr> <- dont pick this                             
                <td><input type="text" name="order1" value="1" id="order1" size="2" /></td>
                 <td></td>
             </tr>
               <tr> <- dont pick this row           
                <td>...</td>
             </tr>
          </table>
       </td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="order_rows">  <- pick this row
     <td>
        <table>
           <tr> <- dont pick this row                           
             <td><input type="text" name="order1" value="1" id="order1" size="2" /></td>
                 </tr>
                 <tr> <- dont pick this row
                    <td>...</td>
              </tr>
            </table>
         </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
```

This is my JQuery that I'm working on.

```
    function reorder(NewOrder)
    {   
    var orderedTrs = new Array();       
    alert(NewOrder);
    for ( i=0; i<=NewOrder.length; i++ ) orderedTrs[i] = $("#table tr")[NewOrder[i]];
    alert(orderedTrs);
    for ( i=0; i<=NewOrder.length; i++ ) $("#table").append(orderedTrs[i]);
    }


    $(document).ready(function()
    {       
        $(".updateButton:button").click(function()
        {           
         var NewOrder = new Array;
         NewOrder[0] = parseInt($("#order1").val()); 
         NewOrder[1] = parseInt($("#order2").val());        
        reorder(NewOrder);
        }); 
   });
```

Comment: What is the problem? Error? Script doesn't work? This isn't a question and it is hard to understand what we should answer. || Also I don't think you need for loop, if you would just load them in an array, the keys would act like the positions.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't evaluated the logic of the rest of your code, but the most obvious answer to your issue would be to modify your selector from

```
$("#table tr")
```

to

```
$("#table > tr")
```

thus ensuring that you select only direct child TRs and not all descendant ones.